# How to change the default background border for radio button using css

Tags: html, css, customization, user-input

How to change the default background border for radio button using css.?
How to change the default background border for radio button using css.?

Answer (score 0):

you may try to use this and to customize it http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css